# Time's Up! rule to guess a number

Tags: times-up

In the third part of Time's Up! (the Peter Sarrett game), I have to mime without speaking. Let's say my partner has to guess the movie "**Seven** Samurai". Is it allowed:

- to mime the figure with seven fingers?
- to mime another figure (six) and mime to add one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume a normal charades-style ruleset applies to the mimed round of Time's Up.  Looking at the "Rules of the acted charade" as given on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charades) I see the following:

> Most commonly, the actor is allowed to make any gestures other than
>   blatantly spelling out the word. In more stringent sets of rules,
>   indicating anything about the form of the phrase is prohibited, even
>   the number of words, so that only the meaning may be acted out.

I don't see how there can realistically be a prohibition on holding up seven fingers to "mime" the word seven.  Any more than it should be illegal to mime "head" by pointing to one's head!  It just so happens that numbers are unusually easy concepts to mime...